# Populating dataprovider Spark List component Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

I have an issue related to populating data into a List. The fact is that once the List is populated, when i want to update the content with new entries and I'm scrolling with the List, suddenly after the update is done, the List scroll to top.

I do not know how can I avoid this behavior, and simply update the dataProvider without the List take me to the top.

Thanks.

Comment: Before you update, get info about the current selection. After you update, reselect it.

Comment: Ant think what behavor do you want if selecetd item is not on list anymore. What if number of list items significantly changes? Where do you want list position in this case?

Comment: When updating, no items is deleted, only items can be added.

Comment: Show us how you are updating.  Are you replacing the dataProvider?  Or adding items to it?

Comment: just adding items to the arrayColletion.